# How do I tell Rails not to pre-render components?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, opalrb, react.rb, opal

When using React.rb how do I keep Rails from prerendering the components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `no_prerender=1` as a parameter to the URL, example:

`http://localhost:3000/leads?no_prerender=1`